# Preserving line feeds and carriage returns when extracting text from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I use VB.Net in VS 2010 professional.

I need to extract data from an XML file that includes line feeds in the text. The line feed locations are marked with the following characters "&#xA".

Using XmlTextReader and XmlDocument I can extract the data I need successfully and display it in a message box and textbox. The text displayed in the message box output shows the relevant line feeds however the text in the textbox has no line feeds, IE it's all displayed on one line.

The textbox multiline and wordwrap properties are is set to true.

The following text is taken directly from the xml file "Photo: Any Image Ltd "&#xA"Ampthill v London Irish Wild Geese"&#xA"RFU National - SSE Nat League 2.

The message box output displays the line feeds correctly:-

The textbox output is: - Photo: Any Image Ltd Ampthill v London Irish Wild Geese RFU National - SSE Nat League 2. (No line feeds)

Since starting this thread, I copied the text directly from the text box into "Word" and it shows the line feeds?

I'm even more confused now!

Since posting this question and after copying the text from the textbox from my application into "Word" as it showed the line feeds I realised that it had to be something to do with the textbox itself.

I replaced my textbox with a "RichTextBox" this shows the line feeds correctly!

I haven't deleted this question, as this tiny bit of information may help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question mentions carriage returns and linefeeds, but your XML string only includes a linefeed (&#xA) character.

TextBox seems to expect an Environment.NewLine, which is a CRLF on Windows. RichTextBox seems to accept a CR, LF, or CRLF as a line break. For example:

```
Dim test$ = "This is a string with a linefeed here " & ControlChars.Lf & " and a carriage return here " & ControlChars.Cr & " and now a CRLF " & ControlChars.CrLf & " The end."
```

This string displays as two lines in a multiline TextBox, and four lines in a RichTextBox, which is the workaround that you've already found and posted about.